# Is it possible to yield two things at a time just like return?

Tags: python, yield

```
def foo(choice):
    for i in limit:
        d1 = doSomeCalc()
        d2 = doSomeOtherCalc()
        if choice == "stuff":
            yield {
                d1 : "value"
            }
        else:
            yield {
                d2 : "Othervalue"
            }
```

I have a function that `yield`s two types of dictionaries depending upon the user's choice

```
def bar():
    for i in limit:
        d1 = doSomeCalc()
        d2 = doSomeOtherCalc()
        return {d1 : "value"}, {d2 : "Othervalue"}

a,b = bar() // when function returns two dictionaries
```

Just like `return` can I use `yield` to give two different dictionaries at a time? How will I get each value?

I don't want to keep the `if-else` in my function now.

Comment: You can do it with: `yield dict1, dict2` which will yield a tuple of dictionaries, and if that's assigned to `a, b`, then each will be assigned the corresponding dictionary. (You don't need to index the tuple's values with `[]` to use them.)

Comment: Yeah, I earlier had an if-else where I was getting one dict at a time but there is no such requirement. I want both dicts and I'll send each to a seperate function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only yield a single value at a time. Iterating over the generator will yield each value in turn.

```
def foo():
  yield 1
  yield 2

for i in foo():
  print(i)
```

And as always, the value can be a tuple.

```
def foo():
  yield 1, 2

for i in foo():
  print(i)
```

Comment: So if value can be a tuple then I can access it like `i[0]` and `i[1]`?

Comment: You can access a tuple in any normal way that you can access a tuple.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey, you could also access a tuple by unpacking: `for i, j in foo():`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to yield a data structure like a dictionary, as follows:

```
def create_acct_and_tbl():
    yield {'acct_id': 4, 'tbl_name': 'new_table_name'}


def test_acct_can_access():
    rslt = create_acct_and_tbl
    print(str(rslt['acct_id']), rslt['tbl_name'])
```